# Fetching weight vectors from Field Aware Factorisation Machines with xlearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix-factorization

I'm using xlearn to train a FFM model using python. How do I fetch the weight vector for a feature value against a field ?

In field-aware factorisation machines, there is one weight vector per *feature value* for every other *field*.

Consider the below training data with Clicked column as the label :

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Clicked        |  Publisher(P)    |  Advertiser(A)   |. Gender(G)       |   
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Yes         |         ESPN     |      Nike        |   Male           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In FFM's there should be one weight vector for every *feature value* (like ESPN) against every other *field* (like A,G). The below example equation from [the paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/ffm.pdf) states this.

```
W(ESPN,A)·W(Nike,P) + W(ESPN,G)·W(Male,P) + W(Nike,G)·W(Male,A)
```

How do I fetch the weight vector W(ESPN,G) from xlearn model ?